# Is it safe for me to use a regex to route webpages with Express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, express, pug

I am running a simple website with Node.js, Express, and Pug/Jade. Instead of repeatedly copy pasting code fragments for every page (like below), I was hoping to use a regular expression.

```
app.get('/notes/document', function(req, res) {
    res.status(200).render('pages/notes/document', {
    });
});
```

Since I am organizing my directory structure nearly identical to the page structure, I thought I could take the requested URL, dissect it, and return the appropriate page. I wrote the below code using a regular expression to access all pages in the "pages/notes" directory.

```
app.get(/\/notes(\/*)*/, function(req, res) {
    const rootDirectory = path.join(__dirname, 'pages/notes/');
    var providedPath = path.join(rootDirectory, req.originalUrl.substring(1).replaceAll('-', ''));
    if(!pathSecure(rootDirectory, providedPath.concat('.*'))) {
        return res.status(404).send('Page could not be found.');
    }
    else {
        fs.access(providedPath.concat('.*'), fs.F_OK, (err) => {
            if (err) {
                res.status(404).send('Page could not be found.');
                console.error(err);
                return;
            }
            res.status(200).render(providedPath, {
            });
        });
    }
});

// Function used to ensure user input is secure
function pathSecure(rootDir, filename) {
    // Poison null byte attack
    if (filename.indexOf('\0') !== -1) {
        return false;
    }
    // Attempting to access file outside intended directory
    else if (providedPath.indexOf(rootDir) !== 0) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

However, I realized that taking user input on the server side and providing access to my file structure may create some serious security vulnerabilities. I am a novice with this sort of stuff, so I was unsure if the method I used above is safe. Are there any alternatives that are more secure or efficient? Also, are there any other security vulnerabilities I should protect against?

Here is the full code:

```
'use strict';

const express = require('express');
const favicon = require('serve-favicon');
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');

const app = express();

app.locals.basedir = __dirname;

app.set('views', __dirname);
app.set('view engine', 'pug');

app.use('/scripts', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/scripts')));
app.use('/images', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/images')));
app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'images', 'favicon.ico')));

app.listen(8000, () => console.log('Listening on port 8000.'));

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.status(200).render('pages/index', {
    });
});

app.get('/about', function(req, res) {
    res.status(200).render('pages/about', {
    });
});

app.get(/\/notes(\/*)*/, function(req, res) {
    const rootDirectory = path.join(__dirname, 'pages/notes/');
    var providedPath = path.join(rootDirectory, req.originalUrl.substring(1).replaceAll('-', ''));
    if(!pathSecure(rootDirectory, providedPath.concat('.*'))) {
        return res.status(404).send('Page could not be found.');
    }
    else {
        fs.access(providedPath.concat('.*'), fs.F_OK, (err) => {
            if (err) {
                res.status(404).send('Page could not be found.');
                console.error(err);
                return;
            }
            res.status(200).render(providedPath, {
            });
        });
    }
});

app.get('/tic-tac-toe', function(req, res) {
    res.status(200).render('pages/tictactoe', {
    });
});

// Function used to ensure user input is secure
function pathSecure(rootDir, filename) {
    // Poison null byte attack
    if (filename.indexOf('\0') !== -1) {
        return false;
    }
    // Attempting to access file outside intended directory
    else if (providedPath.indexOf(rootDir) !== 0) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of directly accessing the path provided by the user, you could use `fs.readdir` to read a list of valid pages beforehand and check against that in a whitelist fashion. That way you're not passing arbitrary paths to a file systems operation, but rather just checking that the requested page exists in the list of existing pages and rendering that.

Comment: How is this protecting against `../../` being in the URL to get outside your public directory?